# How can click on the keyboard right button using R selenium?

Tags: r, rselenium

I want to click on the right button of keyboard using Rselenum. But unfortunately, I get this error.

```
x <- driver$findElement("xpath", "/html/body/c-wiz[2]/div/c-wiz/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/c-wiz/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[1]/section/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/input")
x$sendKeysToElement(list(key='right'))

Selenium message:class com.google.common.collect.Maps$TransformedEntriesMap cannot be cast to class java.lang.CharSequence (com.google.common.collect.Maps$TransformedEntriesMap is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; java.lang.CharSequence is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')

Error:   Summary: UnknownError
     Detail: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command.
     Further Details: run errorDetails method
```

I expect to click the right button of keyboard.

Answer (score 3):

The `key=` values that are recognized by sendKeysToElement are listed in the `selKeys` list. You can see them all with `names(selKeys)`. In this case, the value for the right is "right_arrow", not just "right". So try

```
x$sendKeysToElement(list(key='right_arrow'))
```